# Android send picture through email if we having a picture in base64 format?

Tags: android

I want to send picture with some text through email and I also want to show that picture in my email body.
My code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath( "<img src=data:image/*;base64,#mediaUrlBase64#\">"));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: EXTRA_STREAM is for attachments. Try that with Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. I am not sure whether it will work or not. Also you can try Html.fromHtml("<img src=data:image/*;base64,#mediaUrlBase64#\">"); Either of this should work. Plain guess from my side.

Comment: The picture will not work, other way to do it would be to construct an HTML email.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Did you get any solution?

Comment: @ Pratik Butani not yet